# what is approach of solving MINUS on SPOJ?

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

Link:  http://www.spoj.com/problems/MINUS/

I have an Idea, after doing n-1 operations one can see that there is just + and - coefficients before each number that matters.
For eg.
given sequence: 12 10 4 3 5  and we need to make it a mathematical expression using + and - signs only to get 4 ,one solution will be  +12-10+4+3-5 = 4 ,this expression (+12-10+4+3-5) is get by using knapsack dp, so the exact sign sequence
(+)12(-)10(+)4(+)2(-)5 i.e. +-++- is the required signs sequence and at first stage (+)12(+)10(+)4(+)3(+)5 i.e. +++++ how to get +-++- and what should be sequence of operations?

Comment: The question should be self-contained. What is your question exactly?

Comment: I don't know how to get sequence of operations on converting sequence +++++ to +-++-

Comment: how to decide which sets too be merged at the moment ,say instead of (+)(+)(+)(+)(+) -> (+)(+-)(+)(+) If I do (+)(+)(+)(+)(+) ->(+-)(+)(+)(+) ->(+-)(+)(+-) answer woudnt be same as operations are less than n-1.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include that info? Also the self-contained means that the body of the question should be in your post, not in any external server.

Comment: I want to make it as clear as possible but plz read this answer also: 
 https://www.quora.com/How-do-i-solve-MINUS-on-Spoj-using-dp-SPOJ-com-Problem-MINUS-somewhere-related-to-knapsack-and-backtracking-but-i-am-not-able-to-solve

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have found out the sequence of $+$ and $-$ which lead to getting the final result as the required integer $m$.

One observation here is that the sequence of $+$ and $-$ of length $n$ (size of array) will always start with $+$ $-$, and remaining integers can be either $+$ or $-$. To clarify: if the array is $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, \ldots, a_n$ then $m= +a_1-a_2 \# a_3 \# a_4 \# \cdots \# a_n$,
where $\#$ is either $+$ or $-$.

Now to decipher the order in which operations should be carried out to get such a sequence we first look at the rightmost $-$ in the sequence.

For example, let the integers be $5,8,1,6,2,12$ and $m=6$.

One way to get this is $+5-8+1-6+2+12$.

The rightmost $-$ is near $6$.

Let's add parenthesis here to divide the problem into two smaller ones: $(5-8+1)-(6-2-12)$.

Now solve these two smaller problems individually with same idea of rightmost $-$: $(5-(8-1))-((6-2)-12)$.

We can clearly see the operation that is asked in the question.